# How can I set column widths in VBA for multiple sheets depending on a value in that column?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

Every month, I have to format 12 excel packs so that when the print areas are PDF'd, they all align with the company logo/titles/columns etc. We did make templates and locked the column sizes but the people who are filling these out every month don't like that so we're stuck manually changing them.

What I want is to be able to give VBA a list of numbers and a list of column sizes and for VBA to then look in a certain row on all tabs and be able to change the column sizes dependent on the cell value.

Eg. If A50 ='format' then  --Chooses the tabs to format

```
for cells in row 1 where value is '1' then change those columns to width 11.88.
for cells in row 1 where value is '2' then change those columns to width 30.13.
```

And then the same for the rest of the sheets in the workbook.

For example, in the photo, I have chosen row 1 to have the values in which will determine the column sizes. I can't say if 'C3 is 1 then...' because the business hide columns so the column letters could change month to month.

[image: Example sheet]

Thanks so much in advance!

Louise

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with, looks like a fairly straightforward loop?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, the idea\concept is not enough, show your efforts, explain what\why is not working, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand what you mean by “*Eg. If A50 ='format' then --Chooses the tabs to format*” where previously you stated that you wanted “*VBA to then look in a certain row on ***all*** tabs*”.  Having said that, the following code will loop through ALL sheets in the current Workbook, look at the values in Row 1 (change as you need) and if the Value of the cell is 1 (change as needed) then it will give that column the width you specify in the code.

You haven’t specified whether you’re including column A so I have included it in the code.

```
Sub ColWidths()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

For Each ws In Worksheets
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  
    For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, LastCol))
        If c.Value = 1 Then         'change the value to suit
            c.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 11.88   'change the column width to suit
        End If   
    Next c
Next ws

End Sub
```